# Python Pandas export to parquet, how to overwrite folder outputs

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I am pandas to read a csv file then export it to Parquet partitioned by date, it works great

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('box.csv',parse_dates=True)
df['SETTLEMENTDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SETTLEMENTDATE'])
df['Date'] = df['SETTLEMENTDATE'].dt.date
df.to_parquet('nem.parquet',partition_cols=['Date'],allow_truncated_timestamps=True)
```

and here is a sample output
[image]

When I run the script again, it will generate a new files
[image]

is there an Option in Pandas to overwrite the file instead, and add a new file only when there is a new data ?

Comment: if you can write with `spark` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013126/how-to-overwrite-a-parquet-file-from-where-dataframe-is-being-read-in-spark

Comment: Spark!!!,  i can't really install spark,  this script is run in a small google function,  less depndancy the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue today when using `to_parquet` with partition_cols. My workaround was to run:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq


df = pd.read_csv('box.csv',parse_dates=True)
df['SETTLEMENTDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SETTLEMENTDATE'])
df['Date'] = df['SETTLEMENTDATE'].dt.date

# convert to pyarrow table
df_pa = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

pq.write_to_dataset(df_pa,
  root_path = 'nem.parquet',
  partition_cols = ['Date'],
  basename_template = "part-{i}.parquet",
  existing_data_behavior = 'delete_matching')
```

The key argument here being `existing_data_behavior` which:

> Controls how the dataset will handle data that already exists in the
> destination. The default behaviour is ‘overwrite_or_ignore’.
>
> ‘overwrite_or_ignore’ will ignore any existing data and will overwrite
> files with the same name as an output file. Other existing files will
> be ignored. This behavior, in combination with a unique
> basename_template for each write, will allow for an append workflow.
>
> ‘error’ will raise an error if any data exists in the destination.
>
> ‘delete_matching’ is useful when you are writing a partitioned
> dataset. The first time each partition directory is encountered the
> entire directory will be deleted. This allows you to overwrite old
> partitions completely. This option is only supported for
> use_legacy_dataset=False.

run using:
pyarrow==10.0.1